# Android immersive mode: only works once, toolbar either not hidden or obscured

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

Copied this in from https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html and it works: the app goes full screen, and the system UI comes back when you tap anywhere.

```
    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
    }

    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                //View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                /*or*/ View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
```

However,

**(1)** my application's `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` does *not* get hidden, but it should be;

**(2)** tapping anywhere brings back the system UI which then obscures the `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` thus making it impossible to click the *Settings* button; and

**(3)** after the system UI has been brought back it never disappears again (*cf.* YouTube app where it disappears again after a short while).

What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So this has taken me 8 days!

This is all in `MainActivity.kt`:

Here is the machinery for doing the hiding

```
    private val hideHandler = Handler()
    private val hideRunnable = Runnable {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        Log.i("PSAMFD", "*************** hideRunnable")

        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                )

        getSupportActionBar()?.hide()
    }
```

and we need to run it when we start up

```
    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        hideRunnable.run()
    }
```

`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE` means that the user has to swipe from the edge rather than just touch. This means that their touches don't get confused with touches intended for the app such as button presses and scrolling.

Finally, we have to re-hide after the user has swiped from the edge. The bugger's muddle of the API means that there are two ways to do this depending on the Android version (this goes in `onCreate`)

```
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { view, insets ->
                Log.i("PsaMfd", "onApplyWindowInsets.insets = " + insets.toString())
                if (insets.hasInsets()) {
                    getSupportActionBar()?.show();

                    // Schedule a runnable to hide again
                    hideHandler.removeCallbacks(null)
                    hideHandler.postDelayed(hideRunnable, 3000.toLong())
                } else {
                    getSupportActionBar()?.hide();
                }
                insets
            }
        }
        else {
            window.decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener { visibility ->
                Log.i(
                    "PsaMfd",
                    "setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.visibility = " + visibility.toString()
                )
                if (visibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN == 0) {
                    getSupportActionBar()?.show();

                    // Schedule a runnable to hide again
                    hideHandler.removeCallbacks(null)
                    hideHandler.postDelayed(hideRunnable, 3000.toLong())
                } else {
                    getSupportActionBar()?.hide();
                }
            }
        }
```

i.e., whenever the UI is shown, hide it again after a delay.